# good client for icecast on debian

Tags: debian

I've recently started a webradio with icecast2 on my debian machine. I'm trying to stream live to it with butt (I'm on windows). That works okay. And music from VLC (that doesn't work well at all, a lot of lags).

I'm trying to find an alternative to both. Any recommendations?

Comment: Product recommendations are explicitly off-topic on ServerFault. Please read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: even if it's a free product like butt? Where can I ask this question then.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems

Many of these support shoutcast protocol. There are few flash based players as well which play these streams.

ps. As encoding, you can check each of the media server what encoders does it support. For example, wowza supports all sorts of encoders.

Comment: Hi, but I was looking more for personnal recommandation than an "official" list, that's also why I post here. I'm using EZstream now and everything works fine though, I might have found my solution although it's not really a nice one I find (no UI).

Comment: Personally I use wowza for this. It re-streams also to android, iphone, silverlight and flash over rtmp and http (osmf), also it does works with samsung tv radio and video apps. As encoding I use mainconcept framework which gives a very good quality and performance.